# Getting error in executing windows batch command through Jenkins integration tool

Tags: java, postman, jenkins-cli

Im trying to build a project through Jenkins integration tool. I tried to run locally through batch Command line option. I had earlier installed newman package as well as jenkins.war package to run through local server. But, when i try to build the project im getting an error below. Im a beginner but has no idea how to get rid of this error.[image]

newman run C:\Users\MKBMX500.jenkins\workspace\Exported Collection\CountriesAPcollection.postman_collection.json

This is the exact path entered in the Jenkins CML batch option and i have rechecked the json file has no error at all. Any solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution, not sure it exactly the same procedure or not, but for me the problem was somehow the path of the .json file. I'd copied the json file & paste into to .jenkins workspace folder created in users dir of c:\ drive. Project's name should have to be similar to that of the .json file folder. That worked least for me. Here is the screenshot
[image]

As the name of folder is API_run, so created jenkins project with this same name. Build was completed & finished successfully.